# javascript loop through li in div of paginate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code I'm using. The top part `$('div.pagination...` works fine, I can `alert(length)` and it gives me the correct value of pages in the pagination section. The bottom part appears not to work. This is for a scraper that will open each page on a forum. If I leave the loop out of it it successfully retreaves the url for page [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TcmNH/111). The `length -=2` is to remove the next/previous `li` from the total count.

```
$('div.pagination').each(function() {
    var length = $(this).find('li').length;
    length -= 2;
});

for (var i = 0; var <= length; i++) {
  var pageToOpen = 'http://someWebsite.com/index/page:' + i;
  alert(pageToOpen);
  page.open(pageToOpen, function (status) {
      if (status == 'success') {
          logAuctions();
      } 
  }});
}
```

Comment: in the for loop: for(var i = 0; i <= length; i++)... replace the second var with i

Comment: I don't understand you, `length` and all the numbers that will get using that, might not be that actual `.../page:Number` page you need. What are you up to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `var length` outside (before) the`.each()`

Using `.lentgh` method you might miss the real *page indexes*. So I would suggest to grab the real anchor `href`s.

<kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TcmNH/115/)**</kbd>

```
var pages = [];

// skipping the "Next" and "Last" get all A ahchors
$('div.pagination li').slice(0,-2).find('a').each(function(){
   pages.push( $(this).attr('href') ); 
});

$.each(pages, function(i, v){
    $('<div>'+ ("http://someWebsite.com"+v) +'</div>').appendTo('#output');
});




/* WILL RESULT IN:

http://someWebsite.com/auctions/index/page:2
http://someWebsite.com/auctions/index/page:3
http://someWebsite.com/auctions/index/page:4

*/
```

Comment: why not `var length = $('div.pagination li').length - 2;`

Comment: So my problem was that length was defined in the function and not accessible in the loop?

Comment: In that case you can also think about $.map ?

Comment: @user2007924 exactly, I edited my answer, but if it does not fit the criteria, I can always rollback.